# Need to save a file in C and move it to different location in unix server

Tags: c, unix

i have piece of code in C which is on unix server. their is program which remove's the file in end , but i need to save that file to different location before deletetion.

```
/*  email the message and remove the temp email file.
*/
    sprintf(szCmd,
        "/usr/bin/mail -s\"lg_a17_srvr error\" %s < %s",
        pszSupportAddr, pszTmpMsgFile);
if (system(szCmd) != 0) {
    dce_dbgwrite(DCE_LOG_ERROR,
        "Child %d: command to email error message failed: %s", iThisChild,
        strerror(errno));
    dce_dbgwrite(DCE_LOG_ERROR, "Child %d: email command = %s", iThisChild,
        szCmd);
    dce_dbgwrite(DCE_LOG_ERROR, "Child %d: email message = <%s>",
        iThisChild, szEmailMsg);
}

**remove(pszTmpMsgFile);**
```

}

I need to save this file **pszTmpMsgFile** before removal to different location.

Please help

Comment: I think you just need to change the command line is ok, like `sprintf(szCmd,
        "cp pszTmpMsgFile youWantToCopyFile;/usr/bin/mail -s\"lg_a17_srvr error\" %s < %s",
        pszSupportAddr, pszTmpMsgFile);`

Answer (score 1):

You could amend the code like this:

```
if (system(szCmd) != 0) {
    char szCmd2[4096];
    snprintf(szCmd2, sizeof(szCmd2), "mv %s %s.saved", pszTmpMsgFile, pszTmpMsgFile);
    system(szCmd2);
    dce_dbgwrite(DCE_LOG_ERROR,
        "Child %d: command to email error message failed: %s", iThisChild,
        strerror(errno));
    dce_dbgwrite(DEC_LOG_ERROR,
        "Mail file saved to %s.saved", pszTmpMsgFile);
```

Note that it moves the file out of the way (but in the same directory as before), and reports that the file was saved.  I'd even add a `please remove it soon` after the name of the file in the message.  I don't bother to test whether the move succeeded — there isn't much one can do if it fails.  Note, too, that this is a heavyweight solution.  An alternative is to use the `link()` function:

```
if (system(szCmd) != 0) {
    char szSaveFile[4096];
    snprintf(szSveFile, sizeof(szSaveFile), "%s.saved", pszTmpMsgFile);
    link(pszTmpMsgFile, szSaveFile);
    dce_dbgwrite(DCE_LOG_ERROR,
        "Child %d: command to email error message failed: %s", iThisChild,
        strerror(errno));
    dce_dbgwrite(DEC_LOG_ERROR,
        "Mail file saved to %s.saved", pszTmpMsgFile);
```

Quite apart from speed, this has the additional merit of not affecting the code that removes the original file; it still exists whereas the `mv` command removes it and the cleanup code might report a problem.

Comment: dce_dbgwrite(DEC_LOG_ERROR, "Mail file saved to %s.saved", pszTmpMsgFile);      Can i save file to different location as well using this code and rename this file..  So that the file will be removed...

Comment: I merely took the simplest way out and renamed the file in the same directory (it saved me having to invent a directory name, for example).  You can move it elsewhere, but you need to be a little more careful if you are attempting to use `link()` because you can't link across file systems, so it might become more attractive to use the `mv` command which will work across file systems.  Your call.  Yes, moving the file out of the directory might well make sense.